# How do I create squares of the size I want?

Tags: html, css

I feel a bit ashamed, this should be simple, but I simply do not understand how to do it... ;-)

I just want to create squares with an outer size 40x40 and an inner padding/margin of 2px. So I tried this:

```
<span class="square-row">
  <span style="width:40px; height:40px; display:inline-block;">
     <span style="margin:2px; display:inline-block;"> </span>
  </span>

  ...
```

I get a square with the size I want, but the inner square just collapses and becomes 0x0.

The reason I have an "inner" square is that it should have a different background color.

How can I do it?

*Update*: Yes, I can do it by setting specific height and width on the inner square. And it works in this case, but I wanted to understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: what exactly the output and what you want to know, first add borders to your box in order to see what actually happening, i.e border:1px solid;

Comment: @Xufyan: You should use contrasting backgrounds instead. Borders will alter the width of the element.

Comment: I am using contrasting backgrounds. But as I said the size of the inner square is 0x0. (I can't see it and Firebug tells me the size is 0x0.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are either of these what you are seeking?

http://jsfiddle.net/HrtsX/

If not, could you add a picture of what you desire?

**edit:** As animuson stated, margins apply to the outside of an element, while padding affects the interior. See http://www.goer.org/HTML/intermediate/margins_and_padding/

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I can of course do it that way. ;-)

What I was really asking for was why "auto" does not do what I want. This was a bad example for asking that, but still if someone knows the answer I would be glad to know. :-)

Comment: There must be specific dimensions set for an element or else it will just occupy as little space as possible. In this case, where there are no contents, it will take up `0x0`. So you must set the dimensions (whether it be `min-width` or `width`/`min-height` or `height`). I do not know the technical underlyings as this is from first-hand experience over the years.

Comment: The real reason I asked this was that I sometimes have used "width: 100%" in a div included in another. If the first (inner) div has a border it will overflow the space of the outer div. Then I saw someone using "width:auto; margin: 0" instead. That worked there, but not here for some reason that I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

[It seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/THGtw/).  Note that I changed the background color to red so that I could see the square.

Comment: Thanks. It does not work for me in either Google Chrome or Firefox. What browser are you using, @Jack?

Comment: @Leo - I'm using Chrome.  What, exactly, do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I mean that the size of the inner span becomes 0x0. Does not that happen for you?

Comment: No.  When I inspect the element, the square is listed as 40 px by 40 px.

Comment: I wonder if we are talking about the same span. There are three spans above and I mean the innermost of them. Is that what you mean too?

Answer (score 0):

A margin is applied *outside* the square. You should be using padding to apply it *inside* the square.

Comment: Yes, but I used an inner span instead. (It is not very useful here though.)